# "Bad argument" when I try to set a iptables command

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i ! wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

But i got this error:

> Bad argument `wlan0' Try`iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more
>   information.

I don't know what is wrong, the man says that you have to put a "!" before the conection adapter (in this case is wlan0)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Iain Something about Masquerading http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/docs/HOWTO/other-formats/html_single/Masquerading-Simple-HOWTO.html#FAQ

Comment: I'm trying to resolve the problem posted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/417729/cant-connect-or-ping-to-internet-from-my-device-using-crossover-ethernet/417735

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for. It may also be on topic for http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, i'll post it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this command in this form:

> sudo /usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW ! -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT

But be sure, that interface wlan0 is up:

> sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

Comment: I applied the rule but didn't fix my problem